# Run cron job every 2 hours In the X minute

Tags: linux, centos, cron, cpanel

I want to run cron job every 2 hours In the X minute
Example:
every 2 hours In the 24 minute
00:24
02:24
04:24
etc.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the related site http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put your desired minute in the minute column, and then use `*/2` in the hour column to get it to run every two hours.

`24 */2 * * * <your command>`